# Why can't I enter the value of A?

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I'm trying to write a program where I create 2 children processes using fork. the first child gets a number A from the user and writes it in p1 , then the second child gets the number B from the user and writes it in p2 then the father reads the values A and B and prints the result of their multiplication.I tried this but it doesn't work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>

int main()
{
    int A,B,k,p1[2],p2[2];
    pipe(p1);
    pipe(p2);

    for(k=0;k<2;k++)
    {
        switch(fork())
        {
            case -1:
                break;
            case 0:
                if(k==0)
                {
                    printf("\n Enter value of A = ");
                    scanf("%d",&A);
                    close(p1[0]);
                    write(p1[1],&A,sizeof(int));
                    close(p1[1]);
                    break;
                }
                if(k==1)
                {

                    printf("\n Enter value of B = ");
                    scanf("%d",&B);
                    close(p2[0]);
                    write(p2[1],&B,sizeof(int));
                    close(p2[1]);
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    read(p1[0],&A,sizeof(int)); 
    read(p2[0],&B,sizeof(int));
    printf("\n Multipliction = %d",A*B);
    close(p2[0]);
    close(p1[0]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "it doesn't work means"?  What happens when you run the program, and what output do you see?

Comment: (1) All three processes will execute the lines `read(p1[0],&A,sizeof(int));` to `return 0;`. (2) After the first iteration of the `for` loop the parent and the 1st child are running in parallel; after the second iteration of the `for` loop the parent and *both* children are running in parallel. (3) What makes you think that the parent will wait for the children to `write(p1[1])` and `write(p2[1])` before reading `read(p1[0])` and `read(p2[0])`?

Comment: because I included the break; statements at the end of both ifs ?

Comment: I tried it with : wait (NULL); wait (NULL); but it didn't work too :/

Comment: Please add new informations by [edit]ing your question. And, please, be explicit *what* does not work.